# Не получается выполнить цикл так, как мне надо

Tags: python

Что надо делать, чтобы к списку "result" в цикле, после оператора "input" каждый раз добавлялось новое значение. У меня при новом круге цикла значение в списке заменяется последним введённым от пользователя.

**Вот сам код:**

```
n = 1
while n < 4:
    result = [int(input("Введите число №" + str(n) + ": "))]
    if result == str:
        print("error")
    n += 1
print(result)
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Добавлять к списку - append

Answer (score 6):

Как-то так:

```py
n = 1

# инициализируем массив для чисел
result = []

while n < 4:
    userInput = int(input("Введите число №" + str(n) + ": "))

    # добавляем значение пользователя в массив
    result.append(userInput)

    if result == str:
        print("error")
    n += 1

print(result)
```

Здесь при каждой итерации цикла, ввод пользователя записывается в переменную `userInput`, а потом добавляется в массив `result` с помощью метода `.append()`.

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно)

Comment: @RangeR отметьте галочкой ответ, и проголосуйте за него вверх)

Comment: чтобы вопрос был решённым)

Answer (score 3):

Вообще для добавления элемента к списку используется метод `.append()`

```
list.append(element)
```

В данном случае:

```
result = []
n = 1
while n < 4:
    result.append(int(input("Введите число №" + str(n) + ": ")))
    n +=1
print(result)
```

Comment: лучше конечно `input()` в отдельную переменную выводить, ну ладно уж))

Comment: @PeterKolosov ну это только для читаемости кода лучше, а так необязательно)

Comment: ... и для PEP-8

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно)

Comment: @RangeR не за что) если вопрос решен, то выделите ответ Peter Kolosov галочкой, как правильный ответ)